# If and Else function

Tags: python

> I need help with the following code.

```
phone = input("What is the make of your Phone? ")

if phone == "Samsung":
         model1 = input("Now can you tell me the model of your phone?")
         if model1 < int(4):
            print ("This model and any older models are not compatible with this system, Sorry for any inconvenience!")

         else:
             print ("Let us move on to the problem")


elif phone == "Apple":
        model2 = input("Now can you tell me the model of your phone?")
        if model1 < 4:
         print("This model and any older models are not compatible with this system, Sorry for any inconvenience!")

        else:
            print("Let us move on to your problem")
```

Can you tell me how I would make it so that when you type in anything less than 4 it would say "Model not compatible" and when it is above 4 it will carry on with the code. Thank you

This is what happens when I type a number in

```
What is the make of your Phone? Samsung
Now can you tell me the model of your phone?3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\shs-homes01\011275$\GCSE Computing\MY TroubleShooting code.py", line 9, in <module>
    if model1 < int(4):
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

Comment: `4` is already an integer, why try to convert it?

Comment: `input()` will return a string in python3

Comment: Alright, thanks for the advice.

Comment: I put it in the wrong order. Ill keep it mind for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
if model1 < int(4):
```

to

```
if int(model1) < 4:
```

and you would need exception handling with try as well.

Comment: But what did you mean by "exception handling with try"? Eh?

Comment: If variable A is string, int(A) converts it to int if it contains valid integer value, but gives error if it contains e.g. "five". With "try-except" you can handle these errors.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is you didn't convert model1 to int, it is a string in there and you can't compare int to string.
try this:

```
if int(model1)<4
```

The same goes for the next else if of your's

Comment: The model was the name of the phone but the make is the number, for example iPhone "6", @TigerhawkT3

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 it was the number of the phone as you can see if you would have read the question correctly, the OP even confirms this.